# Can drupal be configured to find modules in another location

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I put my modules in `sites/all/modules`. Is there a way to configure Drupal to find more modules in other location as well

**Edit: Please also check the answers here, on the Drupal StackExchange site:**

**https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/**

Comment: If you ever expect to have other Drupal developers touch your site, you oughtn't move modules any more than stefgosselin suggests, i.e. you can add sub-folders to the sites/all/modules folder to keep things organized, but don't put them completely elsewhere.

Comment: Please don't post the same question here and on Drupal Answers at the same time. This question has very good answers already over here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4618/can-drupal-be-configured-to-find-modules-in-other-locations

Comment: @Berdir, Sorry I posted it here first, then realized I might get better answers at drupal.SE. I wish there was a way to merge answers.

Comment: Don't worry, it's not that bad :) Just leave this be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, but we use a somewhat common convention of seperatating in-house modules from 3rd party modules.

'Home-made' custom modules would be in:

> sites/all/modules/custom

3rd party modules would be in:

> sites/all/modules/vendor

If having subdirectories does not match your needs, I believe you could easily symlink your /obscure/path/to/module directory into your drupal's module directory.

Answer (score -2):

You can put modules in an install profile.